# Draft.js Mention Plugin is not working after rendering contentState to the editor

Tags: draftjs, mention, draft-js-plugins

I am using mentions with the draft.js (like this @yourname) and sending to the database to save and fetching it to render on the web page but things are not working as expected.

On Saving to the database ->

```
const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
const currentStateData = convertToRaw(contentState);
const richStringifyValue = JSON.stringify(currentStateData);
// sending richStringifyValue to save in Mongo DB
```

On Fetch and set in editor ->

```
const [editorState, setEditorState] = React.useState(() => EditorState.createEmpty());
const parsedData = JSON.parse(post.contentStyled);
const fromRawData = convertFromRaw(parsedData );
EditorState.createWithContent(fromRawData);


// here is the view rendered part -
   <Editor 
     readOnly={true}
     editorState={editorState}
   />
```

But after setting in editor (after the data fetched from API) my mentions (@... @... @...) lost the CSS. What should we do?

On Using Edit ->
[image]

On fetch and setting again in Editor ->
[image]

I don't know why is that happening, please help to resolve this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the following:

```
const [editorState, setEditorState] = React.useState(() => {
  const parsedData = JSON.parse(post.contentStyled);
  const fromRawData = convertFromRaw(parsedData );
  return EditorState.createWithContent(fromRawData);
});

// ...
   <Editor 
     readOnly={true}
     editorState={editorState}
   />
```

If you override the `editorState` with a new created state you are removing all the decorators which were added by the plugins.

Comment: Did not work, and I still didn't get the difference

Answer (score 0):

Dominic's answer made me realize what was going on with the decorators, but his approach didn't work for me either.

What I ended up doing instead was to avoid mounting the editor altogether until I have the data inside the EditorState:

```js
const [editorState, setEditorState] = React.useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  const parsedData = JSON.parse(post.contentStyled);
  const fromRawData = convertFromRaw(parsedData );
  setEditorState(() => EditorState.createWithContent(fromRawData));
}, []);

editorState && <Editor readOnly={true} editorState={editorState}/>
```

This way you insert your persisted data into the state before instantiating the component. And afterwards any other plugin adding decorators will work as intended.